# how do i place annotations at the end of the line?

Tags: annotations, plot, matplotlib

my goal is to generate a plot like the following:

[image: Image example]

What i need is to get an array of annotations, then place these annotations rightly aligned onto the plot. How can i achieve this? The text should go until just before the y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use fig.text(). You can do something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(0.8,0.5,'Your text here',size='small',ha='right')
```

The numbers are the x,y coordinates of the text on your figure, ranging from 0 to 1. 'ha' stands for horizontal alignment.

Another way would be to create a secondary y-axis and then use ylabels() to set custom tick labels on that axis.

Comment: unfortunately this places the text field somewhere wrong, because the x-coordinate is not the one of the plot, but of the whole grafic. this answer is wrong

Comment: I don't think the answer is wrong necessarily; I think you should try other numbers than 0.8 and 0.5 to make it work.

Comment: Like KalAurum says, change the numbers to suit your own use. If you have lots of annotations you might be better using a secondary y-axis anyway.